# search doesn't find exact phrase though it exists in the post

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I just found a duplicate and knew one of my posts had already answered it. To get the link, I put `user:me` and a phrase I remembered, `"constructor chain"`, in the search box.

However, [that search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1048572+%22constructor+chain%22) turned up zero results. Only [without the *exact* `"` modifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1048572+constructor+chain) it yields 56 posts, [the first one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25875157/1048572) containing that exact phrase (in the sentence "*There is no such thing as a "constructor chain".*")

Either the search is buggy (not working with whitespaces?), or the *Advanced Search Tips* that are shown on the search page should be adapted. Currently, they contain the entry:

> [exact](https://stackoverflow.com/search) `"words here"`

Also, the [*searching* help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) gives the following basic tip:

> - To find a specific phrase, or to search a string of special characters, enter it in quotes: like `"flat tire"`, or `"<%#"`.

Comment: Likely a x-meta dupe; http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173069/163863 (but yes, it's crap).

Comment: Looks like this gets fixed, it works for me now.

Comment: @Bolu: Really? I'm still getting no matches on the search linked above.

Comment: @Bergi: Weirdly, it now [works for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5tRA.png). It definitely didn't this morning though.

Comment: You can check here:http://imgur.com/ILBMvzr, may be it is because it's one of your own post??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. We're currently running some search tests which are altering the search behaviour for a percentage of users. I am unable to disclose the details of the tests at this time as, like Quantum Mechanics, observing the state may change it. In other words, I don't want to bias you and ruin the results of our tests.

If some of you get the "correct" behavior and others do not, this is probably expected during the tests. If this continues *beyond* the tests, we'll need to fix it.

**Version A of the test's results currently:**

[image: Version A]

**Version B of the test's results currently:**

[image: Version B]

Sorry to be so bloody vague. ;)

Comment: Out of interest, whats the use case for version A being desirable, outside of code? I can't think of one..

Comment: @Matt version A is the *current* behavior, version B is the *proposed* change to the algorithm.

Comment: Pfft... sod A - B testing... **give it to us!**

Comment: @Matt [Stand back! We are doing SCIENCE!](http://store-xkcd-com.myshopify.com/products/try-science)

Comment: Very good,  thanks.  It needs tweaking.  I recently searched "quit" and all the results were for "quite"

Answer (score 2):

Just a heads up, this should now work correctly for all users. Cheers!