# Search box on Stack Overflow being extremely sensitive with keywords

Tags: feature-request, search

First of all, I went there to learn how to search:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Ok, all is good exept that for some reason, I think this search box is extremely sensitive with the keywords... I personnaly think that it doesn't work as good as the Pre-Ask search. I tried it a lot and I found that I'de rather use another search engine because the search box results are... not so good.

And I have the perfect example right here (sorry to bring out my own stuff, I really don't want to, it's just an example)

Go on Stack Overflow and search this:

> How do I call a JavaScript function from Asp.Net Code Behind?

The first question displayed is "probably" EXACTLY what you want.

[image]

But try this one:

> How do I call a JavaScript function from Asp Code Behind?

The qestion mentionned above completely disappear from the list... I don't know how the absence of ".NET" would make the question be irelevant here... In fact, I kind of doubt of the mecanic behind this tool. I guess it's for some reason but what reason?

I even noticed that removing the .NET will narrow the search from 44 results to 20... I don't quite understand again...

Related:

[Why is the "this question might exist" search better than the normal search?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268318/why-is-the-this-question-might-exist-search-better-than-the-normal-search)

[search doesn't find exact phrase though it exists in the post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280378/search-doesnt-find-exact-phrase-though-it-exists-in-the-post)

My question is: Is this the desired behaviour of the search box? Is it meant to be improved or it's OK like that? If it's OK like that... What are the mechanics behind this tool?

Comment: Ho i see... there is not going to be improvement on this ? Ok i'll use google like every one i guess.

Comment: But wait, what is the mecanic behind this tool ???? i still don't get it

Comment: It's better suited for doing (complex) tag searches. Maybe some other stuff. I rarely use it myself.