# Why does Google return better search results for Stack Overflow, than Stack Overflow does?

Tags: support, search

I was looking for information on a Node.js question I had... `check if folder exists node`, so, I searched on Stack Overflow and got the following results, none of which seemed remotely connected to my question:

[image]

Yet when I searched Google, I actually got the results I wanted:

[image]

Why are the top answers on Google on point, yet Stack Overflow's own search can't replicate that? Is it a bug?

Comment: They are working on it.  Turns out searching is hard (ever play where's waldo) ;) Hopefully in 6 to 8 weeks the new search system will be up and running

Comment: Thanks @NathanOliver - is the question relevant or shall I bin it? Useful if someone else sees the same thing maybe?

Comment: I'd leave it.  Others might have different things to say or maybe a dev would like to weigh in.

Comment: I'm sure this has been asked before, but MSO's search is so broken I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @TinyGiant I found it on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199056/stack-overflow-more-easily-found-on-google-rather-than-with-native-search) because I use Google. ;p

Comment: SO search is umm.. 'non-optimal'..

Comment: I copied your exact title to a popular search engine and got: 'About 30,500,000 results'.  :)

Comment: Been asked about 5 times already : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339889/search-box-on-stack-overflow-being-extremely-sensitive-with-keywords

Comment: And i wish you good luck if you want to make a search engine AS GOOD or BETTER than google. Google works only on it, SO has other cats to play with.

Comment: What? Google has other cats too, like Android and self-driving cars

Comment: FWIW, when I first started using the site I used the S.O. search (as one tends to do on a site with a big search box). It took me several months and many unproductive searches to realize it's basically useless as anything other than as a tag filter. Yes, once users know to use Google (or ddg ) they're fine. Until then it's usually a red herring, and at worst downright user hostile to even call it "search".

Comment: It's curious that the answer here isn't painfully obvious. Why is the worlds foremost expert in search technology - the biggest and oldest search giant in the world, a specialist among specialists, whose search technology is worth over half a trillion US dollars and who rakes in something like $100B annually for being so ridiculously good at search - why,  just why, are their results better than some homebrew handwavium search engine bolted on to the arse end of a Q&A community?  I wonder...

Comment: @doubleDown yes it's true, anyway, there search engine is already perfect as we speak so they can concentrate on everything else.

Comment: @J...: Maybe, because that *"homebrew handwavium search engine bolted on to the arse end of a Q&A community"* is so utterly limited in scope, and is written by people with intimate domain-specific knowledge, that it looks to be almost trivially simple to outperform a general purpose search engine?

Comment: I find that Google also shows the moderation here is bad. My questions, found by Google, answered perfectly by users, are far-too-often closed by moderators or marked as bad questions when they were not, and then top the list in a Google search.

Comment: @Mark Correct me if I got anything wrong. Your premises: 1. You ask questions. 2. rep-cucumbers answer them 3. Users who actually care about the quality of the content here close them. 4. Google being a good search engine indexes them and when **you** search for the *titles of your questions* they appear in the top of the list. Please explain to me based on what logic the conclusion of those premises is that moderation here is bad.

Comment: Given that list, I'd say that I was wrong.  But I disagree with item 3. In my view, they are more concerned with being self-important than the quality of the content.  If a question isn't a duplicate, has other users that are helped by the question and the subsequent answers, how does the question qualify as poor content?  The person asking, the people answering, me, and Google all found the question relevant and important.  So I would say the moderation is bad if they are shutting down relevant information that people need.

Comment: @Mark The purpose of Stack Overflow is to build a high-quality library of Q&A for future visitors, and questions which are unlikely to be helpful to future visitors are closed.  Of course you found the question relevant and important because you asked it, and Google found the question because that's its job; Google doesn't care if it's relevant and important.  That leaves only the answerers, and unfortunately lots of users answer low-quality questions just to earn rep.

Comment: Google uses magic. Don't you know anything? :] Seriously though, I don't know any sites that have better performing internal search than Google. No shame here

Comment: Sub-par on-site search has been a problem for a loooong time.  See [Cletus' post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/501/242) and [my post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/50282/242) from 2010 in response to the question 'What's the single biggest barrier to entry on Stack Overflow?'. Both talk about how bad the search is.

Comment: Still crappy in mid 2018...

Comment: @J...I would expect an in-house search platform to out-perform a general search engine. SO guys have better understanding of their system, and yet their search feature is painfully bad. Better remove it altogether until it's at least halfway decent. or better yet - embed an actual google search control

Comment: It would indeed be handy if there was at least an *option* to toggle between using a [Google Custom Search]{https://cse.google.com/cse} ("cse") widget, and/or some options for the search(es) to remember my search preferences.

Answer (score 71):

Part of the reason that Stack Overflow's search is not as good as Google's is because it doesn't have to be. Google has been there from the beginning of SO, and it was always intended to be the primary way for users to find answers on the site.

I don't think Stack Overflow should spend a lot of resources on trying to be as good at search as Google is. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site. That's their core competency, not search. What little time they spend making search work, they should spend making it work *differently* than Google, like custom search operators for tags, questions votes, number answers, etc. Those are things that can help you find what you're looking for in those rare cases when Googling fails.

Comment: If it's supposedly such a difficult problem and so much worse than google why not just use google custom search?

Comment: @Oleg Why? That would just make it the same as Googling. Why would anybody want it to be the same as something that's readily available?

Comment: When people search from within the site they don't know that it's bad which causes them to think that their question wasn't already answered and ask a duplicate, lot's of other bad things can happen when people use bad search without knowing it's bad. Your question from a different angle - why create and use something bad when something good already exists?

Comment: @Oleg I already answered that. Because it's *different*. You're never going to be as good at search as Google. The best thing you can do is return *different* results so that you have a chance at turning up something Google didn't.

Comment: Hmmm `Stack Overflow is a Q&A site. That's their core competency, not search.` But if you can't find what you're looking for from within then surely it's making their `core competency` hard to use?

Comment: Ok, bad is good as long as it's different, got it. The reality is far from what you described it's not just different results it's different **bad** results.

Comment: @Oleg Just because you declare it bad, doesn't mean it's really bad. "Not as good as Google" is a bar so high that nobody gets over it.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney "Yet when I searched Google, I actually got the results I wanted."

Comment: @Oleg I'm constantly on the hunt for bad questions, please don't make it harder for me to find bad questions. [:P](https://xkcd.com/1172/)

Comment: Not just me, but fine let's say that whether it's actually bad or just not as good as google is in dispute. In any case like you said google is going to do it better and it's trivial to integrate tags with it and other custom operations I'm also sure that SO can reach some kind of agreement with google. I don't understand why not use it just for the sake of being different, unless the goal is to make the badness of it a feature for @TinyGiant.

Comment: With all due respect Bill, because you have done a lot of great work here, I could not possibly disagree with your opening statement more. "Part of the reason that Stack Overflow's search is not as good as Google's is because it doesn't have to be.".... It certainly doesn't have to search the entire web, but here locally it should be **better** than google. Can you imagine if this was Amazon's stance? Or Cars.com's stance? Two websites absolutely built on using their local search, filter, and sorting tools. If the intent is to be worse than generic, it should be removed.

Comment: @TravisJ 90% of Amazon's traffic doesn't come from Google. People go directly to Amazon and search. Stack Overflow is *not* built on using its local search, filter, and sorting tools, it's built on being aggressively indexed by Google.

Comment: Amazon in its current form is clearly different than when it was built. In order to grow, Stack Overflow is also going to need to become more of a starting point for searches.

Comment: Google is good for *searching* and finding questions. Stack Overflow search is good for making *queries*. For example “Show me my answers on this particular topic mentioning the following words – because I’m sure I’ve answered this exact question at some point before!” is a very common thing I do. Google cannot do this. And a SO search that worked like Google likely couldn’t do this as well either.

Comment: I'll happily disagree, for two reasons: `1` The search box is at least as prominent as an off-site search engine. That clearly conveys preference. Without an equally accessible and discoverable way to learn, how it is different, it only does more bad than good. `2` The search engine is used while authoring a question to find potential duplicates. At that point there is no way for you to take advantage of its features through custom search operators, and it absolutely, positively must be as good as an external search engine in this scenario. Unfortunately, it isn't.

Comment: @IInspectable I think the built-in duplicate finder is pretty good for finding duplicates. You know - the one that comes up when you're asking a question and asks you whether these other questions answer your question. It's only failed me once, and that was on PPCG where challenges can be duplicates of others, "reskinned" so they use completely different words but have the same base concept.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: My experience is different. For me it *never* produced a viable duplicate while authoring a question, and it hardly ever produced a significant list of duplicates from the close-as-duplicate interface. The experience has been quite underwhelming for years. If it worked reasonably well for you, then that is somewhat comforting. Still, that doesn't coincide with my experience over the past 5 years.

Comment: @IInspectable A better search algorithm might be possible... I wonder whether that would be on-topic for [codegolf.se] (read: crowdsourcing a better one). I'm going to the PPCG sandbox - will link once it's done.

Comment: Here it is: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14034/43394 In a few months, it should be ready for posting to main. A few months after that, there will probably be some answers.

Comment: It would be better to do not have SO search at all, than this useless. It can not even find a question even if I explicitly search three significant word literally in the title. If there would not be search, that would be a clear message: use Google. Sorry for the critic, but most of us are professionals, we know how hard or easy to search a well structured database which title, body and tags. Also, SO is not a freshly launched site, for good sakes, 10 or more years should be enough. And again: in a Q/A database the search the most fundamental functionality...

Comment: @g.pickardou It does not seem at all to me that we know how hard or easy it is to search a well structured database. If you think it's easy, please download a data dump and show us.

Answer (score 55):

The only thing the on-site search is really bad at is finding synonyms. The post you're looking for [doesn't contain the word *folder*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482686/check-synchronously-if-file-directory-exists-in-node-js), as a matter of fact, on that whole Q/A page it is only used once, in a comment. Also you're not leveraging all the search options available by limiting the search scope:

> [`check if folder exists  [nodejs] is:q answers:1`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=check+if+folder+exists++%5Bnodejs%5D+is%3Aq+answers%3A1)

That will give you much more focused result. If you use [the correct wording](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=check+if+directory+exists++%5Bnodejs%5D+is%3Aq+answers%3A1) the post you're looking for is the top result.

I often use Google if I'm not sure about the correct terms as the fuzzy search of Google is much better. If I know what I'm looking for the SE search engine with its custom search parameters will work for me.

<s>If you really want on-site search with Google's engine but scoped to the SE network use the [Stack Exchange Search](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=check+if+directory+exists+node) which is powered by Google.</s>
   Nope, not anymore. SE wide search is backed by Elastic now as well. Tag search works there as well, for example [`[c#] register delegate with IServiceCollection`](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+register+delegate+with+IServiceCollection)

Comment: didn't know about Stack Exchange search, thanks

Comment: *That will give you much more focused result"* - Lol... I always make queries like *"check if folder exists  [nodejs] is:q answers:1"*. What is wrong with people who make queries like *"check if folder exists node"*?

Comment: @jww I'm mildly confused. If there is something that needs changing in me or my post, I need more guidance from you ...

Comment: I tried Stack Exchange Search: ".net register delegate with IServiceCollection" returned the same results as the SO search - one oddly worded question with no answers. Google returns decent SO results. I took those words from the title of an actual question. How bad can it be if I search for what's in the title of the question and it doesn't find that question? (Got it - the word .NET isn't in the title. Removing that helps. But the question is tagged .NET. I always add .NET to searches out of habit so I don't get random stuff from other languages.)

Comment: @ScottHannen sorry, that part of the answer was hopelessly outdated. I've rectified that. My apology  that you spend time on a suggestion that doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 9):

One principle difference: online search as we know it *is not* a pure function of input and corpus - it may also depend on what every other person has ever searched and what actions they did or didn't take as a result, in addition to all sorts of other inputs that may be available, like what *you* have searched, what it thinks *you* are like, etc.

Stack Overflow's search *may* be a pure function of what you type and the site's corpus, but Google's search most certainly *is not*: Google search results also depend on some subset of all other data Google has collected.

Many more people use Google to search than Stack Overflow, so Google has more additional input data available, and Google is also presumably much better than Stack Overflow at using those additional data inputs to produce results, which then in turn can lead to more people using Google to search, which gives them more data to improve search results, which then... you get it.

Comment: You appear to be implying, that Stack Overflow search did not have access to additional information. This is not true. Once you log in, Stack Overflow search has access to your entire profile: Technologies you have worked with, questions you have asked in the past, common spelling mistakes, your way of writing, your site visit history, and much, much more. If Stack Overflow search doesn't use this information, it bares the question: Why not? I still fail to see why Stack Overflow search should not be capable of competing with Google, given its tiny scope plus a priori knowledge of its users.

Comment: @IInspectable he's actually implying that Stack Overflow search has access to *less* information.

Comment: I don't think google is using much information about you to find a relevant answer for you in most case. If you use an anonymising proxy for your google search (like startpage), you still get a better result than stackoverflow for your searches.

Comment: @LucG the implication is that google is using *other users'* information. and that doesn't necessarily exclude anonymous users either, since anonymous users can still click on links