# How can I find duplicate questions before I post a new one?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, search

When I post a question, someone always posts a link and marks my question as a duplicate. Yes, after investigating the linked post, I may find they are similar in the main body more or less, but not the title.

I am new at the programming language I'm working with, and there are hundreds of thousands of posts on Stack Overflow. How can I do better at finding the exact one which is similar to my question?

Comment: And Google/Bing didn't return that post either?

Comment: Try searching on the keywords from your question rather than the way you would phrase it, obviously it can be hard as you may not know what operators are called.

Comment: Why would the title matter? When you search for you basic question you have in either Stack Overflow, Google, Bing or whatever, then it will also check the body, thus I don't understand what your actual issue is.

Comment: Also, as frustrating and unhelpful as this comment may be. The guys posting the duplicate are often people who know other questions already exist. Bit annoying and doesn't really help you I know. What I can suggest is look at Google and using the search. Type something like this "site: www.stackoverflow.com vb.net copy file" That will link to exactly what I need. You could do something similar.

Comment: @Bugs A fairly small portion of the posts I close as a duplicate involve me knowing what I was looking for before I closed the post.  A large portion of the posts I close as a duplicate involve me simply searching Google, finding a question, and using it as a dupe target.  There's also no need at all to use a "site" restriction when searching.  If you find the answer on some other site, you've still gotten your answer.

Comment: @Servy whilst I agree with you on _If you find the answer on some other site, you've still gotten your answer._ I was answering the question _How can I find duplicate questions before I post a new one?_. It's what I do when I want to search for an answer on SO or if I want to find a dupe.

Comment: @Bugs Yes, so given that you're answering that question, why would you bother to restrict your search to SO?  If you find your answer somewhere else, you still no longer need to ask your question.  The question was not, "How do I find duplicates to questions other people have already posted?" after all.

Comment: @Servy Self answering would be one reason why you would want to see if a question exists on SO. It was an idea that's all. I can appreciate where you are coming from though.

Comment: @Bugs Why would you go around intentionally duplicating readily available quality content?  That's not productive at all.

Comment: @Servy, you wouldn't. I was just suggesting that if you wanted to find a dupe on SO, how you could attempt to search for it. Think we are getting our paths crossed or I'm not explaining myself very well.

Answer (score 23):

A few suggestions for finding existing answers to your question:

- Just Google search first. Stack Overflow will always be one of the first results. If you're unsure of what exactly to Google, try writing the title to the question you were about to write, then Google that. It's surprising how often you can find the answer to someone's question just by Googling the title that they wrote.
- Don't use the in-site search for general queries. It's notoriously bad at fuzzy searches. If you're looking for something specific though, the in-site search does have a [few nice features](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), like allowing you to search for only answers, questions above a certain rating, or questions containing certain tags.
- Don't rely entirely on the suggestions that come up after typing your questions title when asking a new question (the "title search"). Only once or twice has that ever actually found a duplicate question of what I was about to ask. Just Google your question title as suggested above.

Note though, don't get down if a question is closed as a duplicate. Search, but be mainly concerned about asking a good question. If you ask a good question, and it's closed as a duplicate, you're helping people in the future by creating another post that links to the right answer.

Comment: going to throw some (hopefully helpful) shade here: `Don't use the in-site search for general queries. It's notoriously bad.` and `Don't rely entirely on the suggestions that come up after typing your questions title when asking a new question` is this mentality [making the internet a better place?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal). [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357462/why-does-google-return-better-search-results-for-stack-overflow-than-stack-over) to my (hopefully helpful) shade

Comment: I feel for the OP, slighlty - I remember some of my first posts being dupe-hammered even after searching first. Hopefully we can solve this discussion in 6-8 weeks.

Comment: @MattR I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean. I don't think the SE search is the best way to find answers the majority of the time, and people finding answers more easily arguably makes the internet a better place. I'm just starting work now, so I'll have to put this on hold for a bit. If you elaborate though, I can try to fix up my answer on my break.

Comment: @Carcigenicate https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190736/what-is-the-origin-of-6-to-8-weeks-and-is-it-really-the-crazy-frog

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks, but I was referring to his first comment.

Comment: "Stack Overflow will always be one of the first results." Not as guaranteed as you might think. However, adding `site:stackoverflow.com` to the query should guarantee it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, blog spam is slowly creeping its way up, unfortunately.

Answer (score -4):

Type the question in the search box in Stack Overflow and it will show all possible related questions asked before.

Comment: [Why is StackOverflow search so bad?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359363/why-is-stackoverflow-search-so-bad)...