# Why is Stack Overflow search so bad?

Tags: discussion, bug

Along with NPE, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException questions appear with regularity. I always wonder why people keep posting duplicates, and [I tried to find the canonical duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=what%20causes%20arrayindexoutofboundsexception), "what causes arrayindexoutofboundsexception":

[image]

Huh?! I KNOW there's a canonical duplicate in the system. Someone else marked the question as a duplicate, and it turns out it's here:

[What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5554734/18157)

Is there a sane reason why my query did not find this?

THIS (meta) question may have been asked before, but I couldn't find the duplicate. Penalizing people for asking duplicate questions if they cannot be found is just silly, and it's kind of sad that SO's search is so anemic.

Comment: `is:q code:ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException what causes` finds it.  I guess "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" isn't being split, and the body instances are in code formatting.

Comment: Wow, that is so 1990's...

Comment: Or use [`what causes *arrayindexoutofboundsexception`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=what%20causes%20*arrayindexoutofboundsexception).

Comment: It's because the people who wrote the search functionality tried to search SO for a solution for how to fix the problem, but found no useful results.

Comment: I've stopped using it years ago since I get way better results just using Google, optionally with a *site:stackoverflow.com* tacked on the end.

Comment: that looks like they're not splitting tokens on periods, which they probably should, especially on sites that are about code. But SE is improving search for the new Channels thing right now, so the situation might improve.

Comment: This should have been closed as a dupe :/

Comment: @MadScientist - Maybe worth noting... Google sells a [search appliance](https://enterprise.google.com/search/products/gsa.html) that allows companies to index their organization. The appliance sits onsite at the organization. From the description: *"Google Search Appliance combines the search expertise of Google with features that meet today’s business requirements—all in one box."* Its also provides support for 20 languages. Maybe the Stack Exchange should use a proven technology rather than trying to implement their own. Google might even donate some to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Servy - I think you mis-stepped when you closed this question as a dup. Why Stack Overflow search sucks is orthogonal to why Google search is better.

Comment: @jww And also [phones home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoning_home)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen - Considering Stack Overflow allows Google to crawl its site for indexing, I don't see how the risk profile materially changes. In both cases Google gets all of Stack Overflow's public pages.