# Relevance fail: Canonical question with 110 votes ranked second after obscure question with one vote and less generic wording?

Tags: discussion, bug, search

> This question is neither inquiring why SO relevance is as good as
>   Google, nor suggesting it should be, and that was already stated in
>   comments. It is inquiring what the cause and fix of an egregious SO
>   relevance fail are, on the basis that is fixable and that fix is
>   generalizable enough, since SO internal search is what users already
>   on SO looking for solutions will use - not Google.

Is the following a relevance bug, and if so how can relevance be improved?
When I search for the **plaintext** [pandas how to pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pandas+how+to+pivot), the canonical question with 110 votes shows up second in relevance behind an obscure and not-useful question; even Q 3. would have been a better hit than 1.:

1. [Q: How to pivot categorical variable in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070423/how-to-pivot-categorical-variable-in-pandas?s=1|113.9259) with 1 vote
2. [Q: How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe?s=2|113.6701) canonical question with 110 votes. Admittedly although tagged [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) it doesn't mention 'pandas' in plaintext either in the title at all, or until about the 15th line of the body. (Shouldn't the 'pandas' tag match 'pandas' in the query plaintext?)
3. [Q: How to pivot a dataframe with pandas so variable columns become rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49185446/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe-with-pandas-so-variable-columns-become-rows?s=3|104.8243)

But the relevance is correct when I search with the **tag** [[pandas] how to pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpandas%5D+how+to+pivot)

1. [Q: How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe) canonical question with 110 votes
2. [Q: How to pivot categorical variable in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070423/how-to-pivot-categorical-variable-in-pandas) 1 vote
3. [Q: How to pivot data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196218/how-to-pivot-data-frame) 1 vote

Less important quibbles: the second Q2. is our not-so-useful friend again, but the second Q3. is a different third-ranked that is not generic as its name would suggest.

(Also, the first Q3: [Q: How to pivot a dataframe with pandas so variable columns become rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49185446/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe-with-pandas-so-variable-columns-become-rows) is really user confusion between 'proper' pivot and transpose; I tried to retitle the OP's title but the keyword 'pivot' should probably be downgraded from being in title to first line of body, to avoid confusing our not-so-discriminating relevance. No good deed, etc.)

Comment: Avoid scrutinizing SO search too closely, it ain't google.  The post contains the word "pivot" no less than 5 times in a small amount of text, that probably made it the winner.  Consider editing it to remove some of them.

Comment: @HansPassant: you make a great point (actually 4 times: unless the word "pivot_table" matches "pivot"). But 110 votes should beat 4/5 keyword mentions in relevance weighting, at least on a 3-year-old question where we know it's not like people accidentally missed a newer much more relevant question. So this is a relevance fail. Right?

Comment: @smci: SO's search doesn't seem to be very high-tech. There's no saying _what_ caused the order to be what it was.

Comment: @Cerbrus: so? I wanted to post this egregiously bad result here so we can learn whatever lessons, and before I dispute this instance by making edits to the titles and first lines of the lower-relevance quesitons. I really don't see the point in downvoting, whoever did that. It took effort to document all this. Should I not bother?

Comment: the question is - why aren't those questions duplicate of one another?

Comment: @Adelin: they're not duplicates, I took it for granted that people can skim the links and see why, if they have basic familiarity with pandas/ (SQL/ Excel/ R).

Comment: @Cerbrus: I'm asking people in general if they think this question was not worth my effort asking. It is not my job to debug SO's (dubious) relevance algorithm. But I don't find your comment at all constructive. There is every say what caused the relevance fail: namely from the people who get paid $$ to work on its relevance.

Comment: @smci: It's common knowledge that SO's search sucks. This has been reported quite often. So, in that regard, this bug report doesn't add anything new to the discussion.

Comment: @Cerbrus "common" as in for everyone that spends 30+ mins per day on meta common... Not everyone is a regular here - and that should not be a prerequisite

Comment: @smci It's actually important that score not have a whole lot of weighting at all.  In past iterations of the related items it was weighted pretty highly and as a result basically every single question ever just had the same few questions that have many thousands of votes, because the 5 orders of magnitude more votes just completely dwarfed any actual keyword relevance values.

Comment: @Servy: ok, and they can can tweak those weights. It seems pretty obvious you'd use log1p(upvotes), not the raw value of upvotes, to avoid highly-upvoted-but-not-very-relevant answers drowning out low-upvoted-more-relevant.

Comment: @smci Okay, and now your 100 scored question is only a tiny bit better than a question with just a handful of votes, so all it takes is a slightly better keyword match for it to be overtaken, and you end up in the situation you have just complained about.

Comment: Well, that's easy to fix! `log1p(keywords)` ;-)

Comment: @Servy: and that's exactly why I said "tweak"... "iteratively"... "discover weighting". For example, there are lots of different algorithms for scoring word-(phrase) relevance from the title and first few lines and rest of the body; the first Q1 is very short but contains 'pivot' very prominently. We could also tweak how sensitive relevance is to matching keywords on the first few lines.

Comment: @smci And you could certainly tweak the values until *this one search query* gives you the result that you want.  But then you've changed all of the other search queries out there.  What's right for this one query (at this one point in time) isn't going to be right for lots of other queries.  And the metrics being used are also very imperfect; there are bad posts with a high score, good posts with a low score, etc.  All of the metrics are just so flawed that there just isn't a perfect solution.  Search is *hard*; that's why search is a trillion dollar industry.

Comment: @smci: Good, you can optimize the algorithms to fix this particular "relevance fail". But in the same change, you'd be reducing the accuracy of other searches. My point is that "search" isn't a core product for Stack Overflow. They don't have the time, money and technological prowess available to make search work like you expect it to.

Comment: @Servy: noone is talking about fixing one isolated instance. Least of all me. I'm working on the basis that relevance is computed on similarity between the query and question title and then body, with lower weighting the further into the answer you go. If you're saying that SO search is so brittle and non-deterministic that we'd just be playing whack-a-mole, then just let me know and I'll give up (citation would be useful).

Comment: @smci: Who says the top half of the question is more relevant than the bottom half?

Comment: @smci You're the one saying that because *this one query* returned the result that you wanted to see most second, not first (which, for the record, isn't even a big problem as you still found the right result), that search is broken and all of the weights need to be re-worked so that it returns the result that you want to see first.  The SO search algorithm does what it can with the rather meager resources SO is willing to invest in it, which isn't a whole lot because SO is designed with the idea that people would use *actual* search engines to find content, not the site's internal search.

Comment: A full re-work of the whole system to give results on par with a proper search engine is well beyond the means of what SO can do, and just tweaking it for this one query isn't useful.

Comment: @Cerbrus: **a quarter-century of information retrieval research says** that's generally the case, at least for long texts. Read about e.g. [the BM25 ranking function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25), and the advances on it.

Comment: @smci: And does that apply to SO answers written by random people? Often, a summary of the answer can be found at the end of the answer.

Comment: @Servy: No, again that's misrepresentation. Not *"because this one query got the ranking and relevance wrong"*. In the years since I've been using SO, I've seen thousands of ranking and relevance fails, but I never posted about them. However this one example struck me as so egregiously and self-evidently wrong that it seemed worth a tiny bit of research to inquire if it's fixable.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I do not know what custom ranking function SO uses. I strongly suspect you don't either. However one of us is making constructive suggestions on how to improve it. If you simply wanted to say *"I appreciate the effort you spent in documenting this one, but this is IMO unlikely to result in a stable, generalizable fix"* you could have said that.

Comment: And I'm saying that we ___know___ search sucks, and that search has a very low priority for SO.

Comment: The dupe target is valid because it both acknowledges that the current search implementation isn't optimal, and it explains why it's unlikely to get better any time soon. I'm not _"misrepresenting"_ you. I'm just saying that your proposed solutions aren't as likely to work as you (seem to) assume they are.

Comment: Looks like this is discussing a problem with search in-house, not between Stack Overflow and another web search engine.  While the workaround is obvious - just use Google instead - this is discussing what could be construed as buggy behavior, so I'll cast the vote to reopen.

Comment: The irony is that the canonical _“Yea, SO search sucks, but it doesn’t have priority”_ answer is now being dismissed because of technicalities. @Makoto: this question is no different than all the other _”Search is broken”_ questions that ___all___ get closed as duplicate of the one I closed this with. The only difference here is that the OP has a different example search.

Comment: @Cerbrus:  If the question *had* mentioned Google search in comparison, I'd have let it go.  Yes, we get that SO search sucks, but the dupe ***doesn't answer their question*** or even go as far as addressing the actual problem.  It's likely a bug (at least it smells like one to me) which should be on the radar of the team that wants to fix search.  It's related, but I don't view it as a dupe.

Comment: @Makoto: The only bug here is the broken weighting system. And that's what every single "search is broken" bug report is about, in essence.

Comment: Thanks @Makoto for actually reading the question, addressing it and reopening the incorrect close.

Comment: UPDATE: 2018/05/24 something has changed in the last 12 hours that changed the rankings on the first search to be more correct. I suspect it was the number and recency of views on the canonical question. (Lesson learned: also post view counts as of <date>, as well as question upvotes)

Answer (score 7):

Yeap, SO search [is broken](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357462/why-does-google-return-better-search-results-for-stack-overflow-than-stack-over#comment519712_357462). But don't expect it to be fixed any time (soon).

The problem you're describing happens because it's notoriously difficult to write an accurate weighting system that properly balances post contents, votes and subject in a way that returns *relevant* results.

The team is well aware of search being broken, but it's [unlikely to be fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357464/1835379) any time soon.

Stack Exchange doesn't have the resources, knowledge and time to rewrite the search engine in a way that is satisfactory. It doesn't have a high priority, because Stack Exchange relies heavily on visitors from external search engines.

Only external search engines have the [resources](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357462/why-does-google-return-better-search-results-for-stack-overflow-than-stack-over#comment520226_357462) required to obsess over *perfect* search results.

Comment: SE search only becomes relevant when you already know what you're looking for and now want to limit results to tags/score/accepted answers/dates etc.